# PostgreSQL memory granted for a single query plan

Tags: postgresql

I'm interested how can I get the information about how much memory/pages did PostgreSQL/OS grant to a query plan for sorting, subqueries, etc.?

Comment: You can see some of that information when you check the execution plan using `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`

Answer (score 0):

Each session is shown as normal unix process and you can monitor those just like you would any other (with `top` for example). There is also dedicated tool for postgres: [pg_top](http://ptop.projects.pgfoundry.org/)

It won't show detailed data about what parts of query plan take how much resources. I guess you can get *some* of it using `explain analyze`, but not much.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL on Windows

Comment: On Windows each session is also represented by individual process. I do not know of dedicated postgres monitoring application for Windows, but any generic one should work just fine. Simplest available is perhaps [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).